revalidate doesn't seem to work with generateStaticParams in nextJS 14
I have a headless nextjs app with strapi on next 14 with the app router. I'm using output:export to statically export my app on ngnix server. I had some problems to generate the static files for the dynamic routes. I solved it by using a client component to fetch the product data, so I separated the logic into 2 files :
page.tsx :
import { getStrapiData } from "app/api/api"
import ProductPage from "."

// Generate static parameters
export const revalidate = 60
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  try {
    // Fetch product data from the API
    const { data: products } = await getStrapiData("/api/products")
    // Map product IDs to static paths
    return products.map((product) => ({
      slug: product.slug,
    }))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching product IDs:", error)
    return [] // Return an empty array in case of an error
  }
}

// Multiple versions of this page will be statically generated
// using the `params` returned by `generateStaticParams`
export default function ServerPage({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
  return <ProductPage params={{ slug: params.slug }} />
}

index.tsx :
"use client"

import { getProductBySlug } from "app/api/api"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { ProductData } from "types/types"
import Product from "@/components/Product/product"
import ProductDetails from "@/components/Product/productDetails"
import { pathBottom, pathTop } from "@/components/SVG/Stroke"

interface Props {
  params: {
    slug: string
  }
}
export default function ProductPage({ params }: Props) {
  const { slug } = params
  console.log("Generating page for product slug:", slug)

  const [product, setProduct] = useState<ProductData | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await getProductBySlug(slug)
        const productData = response.data[0] // Accès au premier élément du tableau data
        console.log("Product fetched:", productData)
        setProduct(productData)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching product data:", error)
      }
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [slug])

  if (!product) {
    return <div className="mx-auto mt-32 w-screen text-center text-xl text-blue">Chargement...</div> // Handle loading state if needed
  }

  const { game_bonux } = product
  const color = game_bonux?.color

  if (!color) {
    console.error("Le produit ou sa propriété color est indéfini.")
    return <div>Error: Product data incomplete.</div> // Handle error state
  }

  const svgTop = (
    <svg
      width="100%"
      height="28"
      viewBox="0 0 720 28"
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
      fill={color}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      {pathTop}
      fill={color}
    </svg>
  )

  const svgBottom = (
    <svg
      width="100%"
      height="28"
      viewBox="0 0 720 28"
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
      fill={color}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      {pathBottom}
      fill={color}
    </svg>
  )

  return (
    <>
      {/* Section Hero */}
      <div className="mt-16 hidden md:block">{svgTop}</div>
      <Product product={product} color={color} />
      <div className="-mt-1 hidden md:block">{svgBottom}</div>
      <ProductDetails product={product} />
    </>
  )
}

It worked but when I add a product in the back office, the params don't seem to be revalidated, or at least the new routes is leading to a 404 error
